# OpenCV crashes webapp on redeploys

Tags: java, linux, opencv, tomcat

I can't seem to redeploy my spring boot webapp without restarting my entire Tomcat server.
Whenever I redeploy, the stacktrace tells me that opencv is already loaded in another classloader and it fails to deploy.

I am using OpenPnP's OpenCV package. https://github.com/openpnp/opencv.

I had this static method in my webapp

```
   static{
        nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
        System.out.println("=====================LOADED CV================" + Core.VERSION);
    }
```

Since the webapp was crashing everytime I redeployed it, I decided to jar up a separate program and uploaded it to my share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/lib folder and run it as a main method to load it once

```
public class SeparateJarFromWebApp{
       public static void main (String args[]){
            System.out.println("==============RUNNING MAIN CLASS===========");
            nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
            System.out.println("=====================LOADED CV================" + Core.VERSION);
        } 
    }
```

After running the command the run the main method of my jar I get the message:

```
 You have loaded library /tmp/opencv_openpnp3438207847480914494/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java320.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
```

Then i ran my webapp without running any commands to load openCv since it was already loaded by my separate jar. But I get this in my stacktrace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(III)J
```

I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the code, it looks like it's initializing some native library. Unless the library allows unloading as well as loading, you're out of luck with regards to redeployment.

You *might* be able to deploy opencv to tomcat's `lib` directory, where it's at least in a place where it will be initialized only once (provided that only one webapp does so), and you'll have to be prepared that any second initialization (e.g. when you redeploy your webapp) will fail.

Why you expect some random `main` method in a jar on the classpath to be executed when deployed to a webserver is beyond me though.

Comment: I run the main method from the command line which loads the library.